# Averages in a grid -- AMC 2012(Australian)

Tags: contest-math, average

In the grid shown, we need to fill in the squares with numbers so that the number in every square, except for the corner ones, is the average of its neighbours. The edge squares have three neighbours, the others four.

[image: grid]

**What is the value of the number in the square marked x?**

My way is too hard: I set pronumerals a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h, and find all other cells expressions about x,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h. for example, the top row, second column is (a+x+1000)/3, etc. Then I have Multivariate linear equations. It is too hard to solve it.

[image: grid solve]

**Any one has a better method?**

Comment: By symmetry, $a=c=d=e=h=0$, $g=x$, and $b=f=-x$. Now try it!

Answer (score 4):

Symmetry might suggest

```
 1000    .  0    .  -1000
  .      x  .   -x     .
  0      .  0    .     0
  .     -x  .    x     .
-1000    .  0    .   1000
```

and then

```
1000     y  0   -y  -1000
  y      x  0   -x    -y
  0      0  0    0     0
 -y     -x  0    x     y
-1000   -y  0    y   1000
```

in which case $y=\frac13(1000+x+0)$ and $x=\frac14(y+y+0+0)$

so $x=200$ and $y=400$

Answer (score 1):

Put the origin in the centre and consider the function $xij$, where $i$ is the row index and $j$ the column index (counted from the centre). (*Edit in response to the comments*: This function specifies the values in the empty squares; it doesn’t apply to the values in the corners that are already filled in.) This has the desired properties. The condition for the squares next to the corners yields

$$
\frac13(1000+0+x)=2x
$$

and thus $x=200$.

Comment: I don't understand your $xij$. It can't be simple multiplication. It looks like you've left out the crucial definition.

Comment: @TonyK: Why not multiplication? (Note that $x$ is the unknown value, not an $x$ coordinate.)

Comment: Because that would give $4x=1000$, so $x=250$, which doesn't work.

Comment: @TonyK: Ah, I see. I should have said that the function is only meant for the missing squares, not for the $1000$ that's already there :-) I've added that.